# Detect highly weighted but also densely inter-connected subnetworks

Tags: graph-algorithms

In a connected / undirected / node weighted (with both positive and negative weights) network, there are many papers studied about the 'Maximum weight connected subgraph' problem. But are there any algorithms (even heuristic) to find highly weighted (not necessarily maximum) subnetworks that are densely inter-connected?

Comment: You'll need to better define "highly weighted" and "densely inter-connected" to get meaningful answers.

Comment: In a connected, undirected, node-weighted network with non-negative weights one can just take the whole graph.  Are you allowing negative weights?  Further, is a bounded degree subgraph sufficiently interconnected, or is something like c-connectivity for small c enough?